# Spring Data JPA Ccould not initialize proxy - no Session when running in different thread in .parallel()

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have problem with this code when I'm trying to run it in parallel and do lazy initialization of some props on MyObject. Whichever lambda is not running in main thread will get exception:

> failed to lazily initialize a collection of role:
>   my.package.model.I18String.translations, could not
>   initialize proxy - no Session

How to make session available in each lambda thread?

```
@Service
public class MyService {

  @Autowired
  private JpaRepo1 repo1;
  @Autowired
  private JpaRepo2 repo2;


  public List<Result> find(String param1, Long param2, Locale param3) {
    return Stream.of(
        findResults1(query, webGroupId, lang),
        findResults2(query, webGroupId, lang))
        **.parallel()**
        .map(Supplier::get)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(toList());
  }

  private Supplier<List<Result>> findResults1(String param1, Long param2, Locale param3) {
    return () -> repo1.findByNameContains(param1, param2, param3)
        .stream()
        .map(cat -> toResult(cat, param3))
        .collect(toList());
  }

  private Supplier<List<Result>> findResults2(String param1, Long param2, Locale param3) {
    return () -> repo2.findByNameContains(param1, param2, param3)
        .stream()
        .map(pg -> toResult(pg, param2, param3))
        .collect(toList());
  }
  private Result toResult(MyObject obj, Locale lang) {
    SearchResult result = new SearchResult();
    result.setResultId(obj.getId());
    **result.setResultName(obj.getName().getString(lang));** // <=====
    result.setTags(obj.getTags().stream().map(Tag::getId).collect(toList()));
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you see works as designed according to the JPA specification (read: has nothing to do with Spring Data JPA being involved here). A JPA `EntityManager` is defined to be bound to a thread, which ultimately means that an entity's lazy-loading state is as well.

So to handle objects in parallel you need to make sure they're fully initialized. Ideally you trigger queries that return immutable DTOs so that instances a are thread safe by design.

Comment: But invocation of .findBy and access to lazy-loading fields is happening in the same thread. In this case I have three threads and each one is invoking findBy and then tries to initialize relationship in the same thread, but it only works in the parent thread. Is there a way to bind session onto threads other than main in spring boot app?